# fatal erro in one line if statment in wordpress plugin [Solved]

Tags: plugins, fatal-error

I hope you have a good day.
I searched for the answer to my question but did not find a solution. please guide me
I want to use *if statment* and  
If the first name of the user is not empty, I will display it,
 otherwise I will display the username
It works correctly with the if statement,

```
<?php
            if(strlen($current_user->user_firstname) != 0){
                echo '<div>Reserved as ' . $current_user->user_firstname . " " . $current_user->user_lastname . '</div>';
            }else{
                echo '<div>Reserved as ' . $current_user->display_name . '</div>';
            }?>
```

but in the ***one line if statement***, the error *fatal error: exception thrown without a stack frame* is displayed.

```
<?php if(strlen($current_user->user_firstname) == 0) ? echo $current_user->display_name : echo $current_user->user_firstname; ?>
```

*I have Word Press version 6.0.2 on local host using Local v6.4.2+6012*
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator incorrectly to simplify your code - it doesn't use/need the `if()`, use it as follows:

`echo (strlen($current_user->user_firstname) == 0) ? $current_user->display_name : $current_user->user_firstname;`

Comment: thank you so much. 
My problem is solved

Comment: If my answer provided you the solution you were after, it would be much appreciated if you marked it as the accepted answer.